# How to replace a route in angular from existing application to another application in angular 11?

Tags: angular, routes

Say I have application A and Application B
which are 2 different app folders.
Application B uses all the login and logout and few other session storage values from Application A.
My requirement is I need to redirect/replace route from Application A to Application B so that it will have all those session values like JWT and all after login to App A.

Little help would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit tricky sharing session data between two applications as each will have its own session space in storage which is different.
You might use `localstorage` to store your data from app A then access in app B if and only if they are running in the same workspace / domain i.e `www.myworkspace.zw/myapp/app1` & `www.myworkspace.zw/myapp/app2`.

But all in all its not encouraged. Find a way to request data from App A to App B either an API or some storage.